# Excel Find intersection of two arrays without VBA

Tags: excel, intersection

I have two columns filled with numbers and N/A. How can I find the intersection of two arrays without using VBA?
Let's say in A2:A8 I have (1,3,4,7,10,"N/A",12) and in B2:B10 I have (2,3,5,7,15,20,40,"N/A",60). I need the intersection, excluding "N/A", which should be (3,7) for this example.

Comment: `vlookup` of shorter list from longer list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `C2` you could use a formula like:

```
 =if(AND(countif($A$2:$A$8, B2)>0,NOT(ISNA(B2))), B2, "")
```

And copy that down to C10. The result will be the intersection excluding `#N/A`

That formula is saying "If there is a match in `A2:A8` for `B2` **AND** `B2` is not `#N/A` then grab `B2` otherwise grab nothing"

It could be simplified and it would just spit out a `true`/`false` with:

```
=countif($A$2:$A$8, B2)>0 * NOT(ISNA(B2))
```

Which is the same thing without the `IF` wrapped around it.

Comment: Thanks JNevill ! It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the expected result (3,7) represents numbers that are both on the same rows in the columns A and B.
I therefore assume that same numbers on different rows will not be included.

column C:

```
=IF(OR(ISNA(A1),ISNA(B1)),"",IF(A1=B1,A1,""))
```